jitbit/CsvExport in Blazor inserts »¿ to the first row, first column of file
I'm using Blazor Server in .net 8. I'm am trying to save a CSV file and am using jitbit/CsvExport to do it. The issue is that additional characters are being added to the first entry.

My razor.cs file looks like this:
private async Task ExportToCSV()
{
    var myExport = new CsvExport(includeColumnSeparatorDefinitionPreamble: false, includeHeaderRow: false);

    myExport.AddRow();
    myExport["Directions"] = "Directions";
    myExport["Leg"] = "Leg";
    myExport["LegTime"] = "Leg Time";
    myExport["Trip"] = "Trip";
    myExport["TripTime"] = "Trip Time";

    foreach (var direction in LoadedDrivingDirections)
    {
        var row = new object[5]
        {
                $"{direction.Maneuver} on {direction.Road}",
                direction.LegDistance.ToString("0.00"),
                TimeSpan.FromMinutes(direction.Time).ToString(@"hh\:mm"),
                direction.DistanceAtStart.ToString("0.00"),
                TimeSpan.FromMinutes(drivingDirectionViews.Where(w => w.Direction.Latitude == direction.Latitude).Select(s => s.TotalTime).FirstOrDefault()).ToString(@"hh\:mm")
        };

        myExport.AddRow();
        myExport["Directions"] = row[0];
        myExport["Leg"] = row[1];
        myExport["LegTime"] = row[2];
        myExport["Trip"] = row[3];
        myExport["TripTime"] = row[4];
    }

    await _js.SaveAs("ProMilesTrip.csv", myExport.ExportAsMemoryStream().ToArray());
}

And my js function is as follows:
function saveAsFile(filename, bytesBase64) {

if (navigator.msSaveBlob) {
    //Download document in Edge browser
    var data = window.atob(bytesBase64);
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(data.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        bytes[i] = data.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    var blob = new Blob([bytes.buffer], { type: "application/octet-stream" });
    navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
}
else {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.download = filename;
    link.href = "data:application/octet-stream;base64," + bytesBase64;
    document.body.appendChild(link); // Needed for Firefox
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
}
}


That looks like a BOM.  If you are writing using a StreamWriter, to prevent it from including a BOM see StreamWriter and UTF-8 Byte Order Marks.

That being said, you tagged this [tag:csvhelper] but are you really using CsvHelper?  CsvExport does not seem to be a type that exists in CsvHelper, according to this search.  If you are not using CsvHelper, what library are you using?  Is it jitbit/CsvExport?

The characters at the beginning of your CSV appear to be a byte order mark.
Since you are using jitbit/CsvExport, the method CsvExport.ExportAsMemoryStream(Encoding encoding = null) has an optional parameter Encoding encoding:

 private readonly Encoding _defaultEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

 public MemoryStream ExportAsMemoryStream(Encoding encoding = null)
 {
     MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

     encoding = encoding ?? _defaultEncoding;


The default value, Encoding.UTF8:

returns a UTF8Encoding object that provides a Unicode byte order mark (BOM).

Since you don't want that, you should pass in your own UTF8Encoding with the constructor parameter encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier set to false:
_js.SaveAs("ProMilesTrip.csv", 
           myExport.ExportAsMemoryStream(encoding : new UTF8Encoding(false)).ToArray());


That worked well. Thank you.

@Mardymar68 - you're welcome.  I went ahead and edited your question to clarify that you are using jitbit/CsvExport.
